# Viewport content width device-width plus [ input ]

Tags: html, css, viewport

Is there a way I can have the viewport width be the device-width + ()pixels

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>
```

Comment: No, you cannot adjust the [**META viewport**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to be a specific number of pixels... but why are you trying to do such a thing? If you're trying to adjust how your site looks at certain widths, you use [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for that.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I am trying to override the width css from js element.style without !important

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override Inline Styles added via JS with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281633/override-inline-styles-added-via-js-with-css)